# Change Maximage jquery background image depending on device resolution

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, background-image, resolution, device

New to jquery so bear with me if my attempts seems a little lame.

Using the Maximage jquery plugin (http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/) I added a full screen background to my homepage, all well and good. But ideally I needed to change the resolution of the images selected depending upon the device resolution in a way which would be compliant with older browsers. Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck with the resolution the images are first set? I tried the following:

```
<div id="maximage" class="mc-cycle">

    <div class="mc-image">
          <img src="images/small/property1.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="mc-image">
          <img src="images/small/property2.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="mc-image">
          <img src="images/small/property3.jpg" />
    </div>

</div>
```

When maximage runs, it strips out the image tags and applies the original image path as a background image instead. I tried to change this like so...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var winheight = $(window).height();
    var winwidth = $(window).width();
    var previousWinSetting = 700; //low res image starter

    function changeImgPath(pathTweak){
        var imgDivArray = $('div.mc-image');
        for(var i=0; i<imgDivArray.length; i++){
            var selectedSrc = $("div.mc-image").css('background-image');     
            var splitSrc = selectedSrc.split('/');
            splitSrc[splitSrc.length-1] = splitSrc[splitSrc.length-1].slice(0,-1); //Trim last character ")"
            var newSrc = "properties/"+pathTweak+"/"+splitSrc[splitSrc.length-1];
            alert(newSrc);
            $("div.mc-image").css("background-image", "url("+newSrc+")");
        }
    }

//refresh on resize
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > previousWinSetting && $(window).width() >= 640  && $(window).width() < 1010) {
            changeImgPath("medium");
            previousWinSetting = 1000;   
        }

        if ($(window).width() > previousWinSetting && $(window).width() >= 1010) {
            changeImgPath("full");
            previousWinSetting = 5000;
        }
    });

    $(function() { //Change path when document ready
        if ((window).width() < 1010 && (window).width() >750){
            changeImgPath("medium"); previousWinSetting = 1000;
        } else if ((window).width() >= 1010) {
        changeImgPath("full"); previousWinSetting = 5000;
        }
    });

</script>
```

At the moment each div.mc-image has its background set to match the first .mc-image instance (property1.jpg). While I'm sure that's to do with my loop (maybe change $("div.mc-image") to imgDivArray[i]), the bigger concern is the fact by changing the background image-path it seems to switch off the maximage functionality. Images immediately stopped being scaled to fill the screen.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Okay another day and a clearer head. Rather than access the background-image property generated by the maximage plugin, I thought it would be easier to add id attributes to the plug-ins generated div tags instead. Like so:

```
// Create a div with a background image so we can use CSS3's position cover (for modern browsers)
$self.append('<div class="mc-image ' + $img.theclass + '" title="' + $img.alt + '" style="background-image:url(\'' + $img.url + '\');' + $img.style + '" data-href="'+ $img.datahref +'" id="prop'+i+'">'+ $img.content +'</div>');
```

... and later on for older browser support ...

```
// Create Div
$div = $("<div id='prop"+j+"'>" + c + "</div>").attr("class", "mc-image mc-image-n" + j + " " + $.Slides[j].theclass);
```

This then generates a series of ids like so - prop0, prop1, prop2 etc. After this I simply added some media query css, note if you don't add the !important, the inline CSS styling will over-rule the media query CSS rules...

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (min-width: 710px) and (max-width : 1010px) {
        #prop0 {background-image:url(properties/medium/image0.jpg) !important;}
        #prop1 {background-image:url(properties/medium/image1.jpg) !important;}
        #prop2 {background-image:url(properties/medium/image2.jpg) !important;}
        #prop3 {background-image:url(properties/medium/image3.jpg) !important;}
        #prop4 {background-image:url(properties/medium/image4.jpg) !important;}
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1011px) {
        #prop0 {background-image:url(properties/full/image0.jpg) !important;}
        #prop1 {background-image:url(properties/full/image1.jpg) !important;}
        #prop2 {background-image:url(properties/full/image2.jpg) !important;}
        #prop3 {background-image:url(properties/full/image3.jpg) !important;}
        #prop4 {background-image:url(properties/full/image4.jpg) !important;}
    }
</style>
```

Testing at the moment, but all seems fine so far on android tablets and phones, as well as an older PC running IE ...haven't tested it on an ipad yet though!